# textarea reset on v-model doesn't reset the text in textarea

Tags: vue.js, textarea, bootstrap-vue

I want to reset the text in textarea when user clicks the undo button.

The data property `heading` which is input and `body` which is textarea are getting reset indeed, but I only see the heading input being reset, the textarea for body does remove the text.

```
<form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
  <input  v-model="heading" placeholder="Heading" />
  <textarea  v-model="body" placeholder="Note..." />
  <button type="submit" ><i class="material-icons">send</i></button>
  <button type="button" @click="resetNote" ><i class="material-icons">undo</i></button>
</form>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      heading: '',
      body: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetNote() {
      console.log('resetNote')
      this.heading = '';
      this.body = '';
    },
    handleSubmit() {
      console.log('handleSubmit')
      console.log(`${this.heading} - ${this.body}`)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Both reset for me. Maybe you just need to rebuild/refresh.

Comment: Same here I can not reproduce, only buttons where not displayed as you didn't close the textarea the proper way: https://jsfiddle.net/dreijntjens/mu093dbf/4/

Comment: Thanks guys, the fiddle helped! I guess my custom textarea component was broken. Having changed that to a bootstrap textarea works fine.